# ListView Item and OnClick problem

Tags: android, android-layout

When you touch some grid or listview items in an android app, he change the background color telling you that you have pressed it. 
I'm having a problem in my app. When I create that a listview for instance, and I press it in my phone, he change color, but if I set the OnClick property, the item dont change it color. Whats wrong? The OnClick works as its suppose.

Thanks

Comment: could you post the code in question?

Comment: are you setting onclick on the items, or on the listview itself?

Answer (score 0):

Generally with ListView you want to use an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

This gives you a chance to perform an action based on the position in the list that was clicked.

If you need access to the view adapter from within `onItemClick` then you can use [AdapterView#getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getAdapter%28%29) on the `AdapterView` that is supplied to you.